# AWS Data Migration Service IAM Policy Error?

Tags: elasticsearch, data-migration

In AWS DMS, I am having an error when I try to create Target Endpoint.
I am trying to migrate MariaDB to Elasticsearch, and so the service of Target Endpoint is AWS Elasticsearch service.
However, it requires me to add IAM user but even I add an IAM user with Administrator policy it keeps saying that
`The IAM Role arn:aws:iam::[number]:user/[username] is not configured properly.AccessDenied`

What kind of IAM policies are required for this task?

Answer (score 0):

you can get the policy document from here
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Target.DynamoDB.html